# RadioGroup in Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, radio-button, radio-group

Hello guys I am new to Java, I am developing a system for tablet, and I'm having trouble working with the ListView; My ListView has 1 with 3 RadioButton, RadioGroup carry data from the SqlLite, good up there all right, I carry the list with the windgets and with the data I want, I can usually select the RadioButton.
The problem is, I want to save in the database the contents of the RadioButton and the item id, so the RadioButton is selected.

```
        lvPerguntas = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPergunta);
        mPerguntasList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cPerguntas = DataBase.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbPerguntas WHERE Id_Topico='"+IdTopico+"'",null);
        while (cPerguntas.moveToNext()){
            mPerguntasList.add(new Itens_Perguntas(cPerguntas.getInt(0), cPerguntas.getString(2)));
        }

        adapter = new Adapter_Perguntas(getApplicationContext(), mPerguntasList);
        lvPerguntas.setAdapter(adapter);

        rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.GroupResposta);

        lvPerguntas.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                        switch (checkedId) {
                            case R.id.rbConforme:
                                DataBase.db.execSQL("UPDATE tbDados SET Test='"+position+"Conforme' WHERE Id_Dado='1';");
                                break;
                            case R.id.rbNConforme:
                                DataBase.db.execSQL("UPDATE tbDados SET Test='"+position+"Não Conforme' WHERE Id_Dado='1';");
                                break;
                            case R.id.rbNAplica:
                                DataBase.db.execSQL("UPDATE tbDados SET Test='"+position+"Não se aplica' WHERE Id_Dado='1';");
                                break;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need add OnCheckedChangeListener to radiogroup and a flag in Itens_Perguntas to save position radio button seleted.

Comment: Onde eu colocaria o OnCheckedChangeListener ?